When is it necessary to call services.AddMemoryCache()?
I am writing some middleware that would benefit from a memory cache. So I'm using dependency injection to provide an IMemoryCache instance.
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IMemoryCache cache)
{
    // Access cache here...
}

This seems to be working, but I have a few questions.

The instructions I found said to call services.AddMemoryCache() in my initialization. But it works fine if I don't. Can someone tell me what this method does and when I need to call it?
What is the lifetime of the data stored in the cache?


The MemoryCache allows you to set an expiration for a cache item, but note that all data is cleared when the app restarts

Then you already have IMemoryCache registered.  It adds a singleton.  See the source here.

You may be registering other services that register IMemoryCache. For example, in AddRazorViewEngineServices if you're using MVC/RP.

@KirkLarkin: Yeah, perhaps. Not sure what it would be though.

Are you using AddControllersWithViews or AddRazorPages? Those were the only calls I can find in the ASP.NET Core framework that do it.

@KirkLarkin: I'm definately using AddRazorPages().

That'll be it then. It ends up with the line I highlighted being called. It doesn't hurt if you call AddMemoryCache yourself though, as it will only be registered once.

@KirkLarkin: I don't know what line you highlighted related to AddRazorPages(). If you can show where this is happening, and want to write it in an answer, I would mark that as the correct answer.


It will register it in your DI so that it can be used. Failure to set it in the DI container will make it an unresolved service. See a working fiddle here;
The lifetime will be until it is cleared. It can be cleared by command or by setting the lifetime for the cached item. This can be done globally or individually like in the example below.

package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory
package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions

// program.cs

// add it without options 
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

// set global expiry for memory
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache(opts => new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
    .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
    .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
);

// in your task (only set the absolute)
cache.Set("key", "value", TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

As was pointed out above it is volatile and will not survive an application reset

There are 2 hard problems in computer science: 
cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors.


Thanks, but your answer to #1 does not answer why it works if I don't use it, and when I need it vs when I don't.

I have added a fiddle. Un/Comment line 10 to see a change in applications opperation

You need to add memory cache service into Program.cs
If i  give you some suggestion about it, you should create a wrapper to use memory cache. However you cannot add unit tests. Because most of func are static.
For second question  you can use MemoryCacheEntryOptions class. There are so many option for cache. If you would like to store too long time you can set .SetAbsoluteExpiration(DateTimeOffset.MaxValue) like that
 var options= new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                        .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
                        .SetAbsoluteExpiration(DateTimeOffset.MaxValue)
                        .SetPriority(CacheItemPriority.High);

